# Share read-only objects between processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use a "keep alive" processes model (who communicates with Pipes with main process) in my software, and I'm trying to share read-only objects between them and the main process. An example to show my problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe#, Manager
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
import os


def start_in_oneshot_processes(obj, nb_process):
    """
    Start nb_process processes to do the job. Then process finish the job they die.
    """
    processes = []
    for i in range(nb_process):
        #  Simple process style
        p = Process(target=oneshot_in_process, args=(obj,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        # Wait all process finish
        process.join()

def oneshot_in_process(obj):
    """
    Main job (don't matter if in oneshot, keeped alive process. It have job to do)
    """
    print('p', obj, os.getpid())


def start_in_keepedalive_processes(obj, nb_process):
    """
    Start nb_process and keep them alive. Send job to them multiple times, then close thems.
    """
    processes = []
    readers_pipes = []
    writers_pipes = []
    for i in range(nb_process):
        # Start process with Pipes for communicate
        local_read_pipe, local_write_pipe = Pipe(duplex=False)
        process_read_pipe, process_write_pipe = Pipe(duplex=False)
        readers_pipes.append(local_read_pipe)
        writers_pipes.append(process_write_pipe)
        p = Process(target=run_keepedalive_process, args=(local_write_pipe, process_read_pipe, obj))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    # Send to process some job to do
    for job in range(3):
        print('send new job to processes:')
        for process_number in range(nb_process):
            # Send data to process
            writers_pipes[process_number].send(obj)
            reader_useds = []
        # Wait response from processes
        while readers_pipes:
            for r in wait(readers_pipes):
                try:
                    r.recv()
                except EOFError:
                    pass
                finally:
                    reader_useds.append(r)
                    readers_pipes.remove(r)
        readers_pipes = reader_useds

    # Kill processes
    for writer_pipe in writers_pipes:
        writer_pipe.send('stop')

def run_keepedalive_process(main_write_pipe, process_read_pipe, obj):
    """
    Procees who don't finish while job to do
    """
    while obj != 'stop':
        oneshot_in_process(obj)
        # Send to main process "I've done my job"
        main_write_pipe.send('job is done')
        # Wait for new job to do (this part can be simplified no ?)
        readers = [process_read_pipe]
        while readers:
            for r in wait(readers):
                try:
                    obj = r.recv()
                except EOFError:
                    pass
                finally:
                    readers.remove(r)


obj = object()
print('m', obj, os.getpid())

print('One shot processes:')
start_in_oneshot_processes(obj, 5)

print('Keeped alive processes:')
start_in_keepedalive_processes(obj, 5)

print('f', obj, os.getpid())
```

Output is:

```
➜  sandbox git:(dev/opt) ✗ python3.4 sharedd.py
m <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3225
One shot processes:
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3227
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3226
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3229
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3228
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3230
Keeped alive processes:
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3231
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3232
send new job to processes:
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3235
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3233
p <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3234
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3231
send new job to processes:
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3232
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3235
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3234
p <object object at 0xb7266490> 3231
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3233
p <object object at 0xb7266490> 3232
p <object object at 0xb7266490> 3235
p <object object at 0xb7266490> 3233
send new job to processes:
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3232
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3235
p <object object at 0xb7266490> 3234
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3231
f <object object at 0xb7266dc8> 3225
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3233
p <object object at 0xb7266488> 3234
```

If I create simple processes (start_in_oneshot_processes), `obj` have the same memory address in subprocess and in main process: **0xb7266dc8**.

But when my process receive objects with a Pipe (start_in_keepedalive_processes), objects memory address are not the same as the main process: example: **0xb7266488** instead of **0xb7266dc8**.
These objects are read-only by sub processes. How can I share them between main process and subprocess (and save memory copy time) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want using `Pipe`.  When data is sent through a pipe to another process, that process has to store a copy of the data in its own address space --- a new object, in Python.  Most other methods of shipping data between processes are the same.

It's only coincidence that you saw the same memory address from the `start_in_oneshot_process` function, likely due to your choice of operating system.  In general, two processes won't share the same RAM at all.  (Check the `Process` docs section on [Contexts and Start Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) for the differences between Windows `spawn` and Unix `fork`.)

If it's *really* important that two processes can inspect the same chunk of memory, you can try either [shared memory or an object manager process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).  Note that those same docs tell you that this rarely a good idea.